# Why doesn't onClick activate function?

Tags: javascript, onclick, submit

I'm trying to write a simple code in JavaScript where selecting a button calls a prompt function, but the prompt never pops.

This is the HTML:

```
    <div id="btnDiv">
    <button type="submit" id="btn" onclick="submit"> send info </button>
    </div>
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    prompt("Thank you");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with how you're structuring this? You could be trying to attach an event to an element that doesn't exist yet. Also, `prompt` expects an input. You want `alert` here.

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console for any error reports?

Comment: You need to attach the event handler after adding it in the DOM, otherwise `document.getElementById("btn")` won't find anything.

Comment: Hi @SterlingArcher Archer, you're right, I changed the 'prompt' into 'alert'.
This is my fiddle code, in which the function actually works (it didn't work locally): https://jsfiddle.net/hr2ss2b7/3/

NewToJS- Running the code locally, I get following error:
_Uncaught ReferenceError: submit is not defined_

Spencer,  I'll try it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the JS code is loaded after the HTML content, you can use onLoad event:

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
      prompt("Thank you");
    }
};
```